# How and when to use こと

Tags: particle-こと

I have seen こと used in many sentences, but I'm not really sure what it is actually doing. I may have seen something that implies it means "thing", but sometimes the sentence it's in doesn't really track that. Information on こと, any at all, would be a great help!

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

Aside from the "thing" meaning, the main function of こと is to work as a "nominalizer" and making sentences become nouns. You should use websites like IMABI or maybe TaeKim in order to understand the uses in a more coherent way.